# How can I parse a text file in d3 based on headers?

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, text

I have a text file that's formatted as such:

**Header 1**

...
Some Text
...

**Header 2**

...
Some Text
...

How can I parse this so that I have a structure with key-value pairs as `{Header 1 : SomeText, Header 2 : SomeText}`?

Right now, when I do 
`d3.text("textFile.txt", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});`

I receive the entire text file.

P.S. This is a sample text file:

**Bold Title 1**

SomeText on Line 1

SomeTextOnLine2

**Bold Title 2**

SomeText on Line 1

SomeTextOnLine2

Comment: will you share some text  format from text file ?

Comment: Where is the text file coming from?

Comment: Do you have any programmatic way to determine what text is bold and what isn't? It's easy for humans to distinguish between bold and non-bold text, but if you're trying to some code to do it, it's a very different issue.